# JavaScript library to upload a file

Tags: javascript

Is there a library that will allow me to download a user's profile photo and upload it?

Comment: Reading between the lines (and doing some searching with Google) I'm guessing that this has something to do with Facebook. You might want to be explicit about that, "JavaScript Client Library" is an amazingly generic name!

Comment: Google: "{Name of Website} API"

Comment: Yes,my question related with API

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just retrieve the file then you are best off just using an `img` tag and changing where it points to, but, if you want to access the hard drive of the user, it really depends on how limited of browser support you want.

You may want to look at DOM Storage though.

These links may help:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197062(v=VS.85).aspx

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage

In Firefox 3.6 they added a File API:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications